# ANTLR4 parse rule to match open/close brackets

Tags: antlr4

I'm parsing a language that has a statement 'code' followed by '{', followed by a bunch of code that I have no interest in parsing, followed by '}'. I'd ideally like to have a rule like:

`skip_code: 'code' '{' ~['}']* '}'`

..which would simply skip ahead to the closing curly brace. The problem is that the code being skipped could itself have pairs of curly braces. So, what I essentially need to do is run a counter and increment on each '{' and decrement on each '}', and end the parse rule when the counter is back to 0.

What's the best way of doing this in ANTLR4? Should I skip off to a custom function when 'code' is detected and swallow up the tokens and run my counter, or is there some elegant way to express this in the grammar itself?

EDIT: Some sample code, as requested:

```
class foo;
  int m_bar;
  function foo_bar;
     print("hello world");
  endfunction
  code {
     // This is some C code
     void my_c_func() {
        printf("I have curly braces {} in a string!");
     }
  }
  function back_to_parsed_code;
  endfunction
endclass
```

Comment: Could you post a real example of the code you're parsing?

Comment: Are there string literals (that might include a `{` or `}`) inside the code block you want to ignore? Are there comments inside those code blocks (that might include a `{` or `}`)? You could go for Mike's suggestion, but discarding these code blocks during lexing might be easier. Discarding them in the parser would mean that everything inside the `{ ... }` will still need to be tokenized.

Comment: @BartKiers Yeah, the content within the curly braces could be considered fully legal C code, with its own strings, curly braces, and so on, which make it tricky to do in lexer. Ideally, I don't want to even tokenize that code, but Mike's suggestion does make it very easy to implement in the parser. Any suggestions on how that could be done in the lexer?

Comment: Have you tried my block rule as a lexer rule? Should still work. The only restriction in both cases is that the curly braces must be balanced.

Comment: @Mike, it won't work if the code block contain strings or comment containing braces themselves.

Comment: @Stan I'll post a small demo later on, if someone else doesn't before that time.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use something like:

```
skip_code: CODE_SYM block;
block: OPEN_CURLY (~CLOSE_CURLY | block)* CLOSE_CURLY;

CODE_SYM: 'code';
OPEN_CURLY: '{';
CLOSE_CURLY: '}';
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd handle these code blocks in the lexer. A quick demo:

```antlr
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String source = "class foo;\n" +
                "  int m_bar;\n" +
                "  function foo_bar;\n" +
                "     print(\"hello world\");\n" +
                "  endfunction\n" +
                "  code {\n" +
                "     // This is some C code }}} \n" +
                "     void my_c_func() {\n" +
                "        printf(\"I have curly braces {} in a string!\");\n" +
                "     }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "  function back_to_parsed_code;\n" +
                "  endfunction\n" +
                "endclass";

        System.out.printf("Tokenizing:\n\n%s\n\n", source);

        DemoLexer lexer = new DemoLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(source));

        for (Token t : lexer.getAllTokens()){
            System.out.printf("%-20s '%s'\n",
                    DemoLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()),
                    t.getText().replaceAll("[\r\n]", "\\\\n")
            );
        }
    }
}
```

If you run the class above, the following will be printed:

```
Tokenizing:

class foo;
  int m_bar;
  function foo_bar;
     print("hello world");
  endfunction
  code {
     // This is some C code }}} 
     void my_c_func() {
        printf("I have curly braces {} in a string!");
     }
  }
  function back_to_parsed_code;
  endfunction
endclass

ID                   'class'
ID                   'foo'
ANY                  ';'
ID                   'int'
ID                   'm_bar'
ANY                  ';'
ID                   'function'
ID                   'foo_bar'
ANY                  ';'
ID                   'print'
ANY                  '('
STRING               '"hello world"'
ANY                  ')'
ANY                  ';'
ID                   'endfunction'
ID                   'code'
BLOCK                '{\n     // This is some C code }}} \n     void my_c_func() {\n        printf("I have curly braces {} in a string!");\n     }\n  }'
ID                   'function'
ID                   'back_to_parsed_code'
ANY                  ';'
ID                   'endfunction'
ID                   'endclass'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md) for your purpose. Take attention on two modes for CODE section. Yoy can not properly close CODE section with only one mode.

**Lexer**

```
lexer grammar Question_41355044Lexer;

CODE: 'code';
LCURLY: '{' -> pushMode(CODE_0);
WS:    [ \t\r\n] -> skip;

mode CODE_0;

CODE_0_LCURLY: '{' -> type(OTHER), pushMode(CODE_N);
RCURLY: '}' -> popMode;     // Close for LCURLY
CODE_0_OTHER: ~[{}]+ -> type(OTHER);

mode CODE_N;

CODE_N_LCURLY: '{' -> type(OTHER), pushMode(CODE_N);
CODE_N_RCURLY: '}' -> type(OTHER), popMode;
OTHER: ~[{}]+;
```

**Parser**

```
parser grammar Question_41355044Parser;

options { tokenVocab = Question_41355044Lexer; }

skip_code: 'code' LCURLY OTHER* RCURLY;
```

**Input**

```
code {
   // This is some C code
   void my_c_func() {
      printf("I have curly braces {} in a string!");
   }
}
```

**Output tokens**

```
CODE LCURLY({) OTHER(   // Th...) OTHER({) OTHER(      pr...) 
OTHER({) OTHER(}) OTHER( in a st...) OTHER(}) OTHER() RCURLY(}) EOF
```

The same approach is used for ANTLR grammar parsing itself: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/antlr4

But runtime code `LexerAdaptor.py` is used there instead of two-level modes.